# Hibernate entity with more than two OneToMany fields

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();

    // Many more, including a primary key
}
```

Starting the application, I got the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

If I remove one arbitary `OneToMany` association, or if I add a `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)` to an arbitary `OneToMany` association, everything works fine.

Is this a hibernate bug, a hibernate limitation, or is there anything wrong with my entity? TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug. It is because of Hibernate uses a one select with a join to fetch all the data. Hibernate can join three and more tables, but the result of joining will have duplicates of, for example, `Address` columns. Hibernate needs to remove duplicates — it is a reason why `Set` works.

Possible workarounds:

- Use `Set<Address>` instead of `List<Address>`. You should use `Set` for all collections.
- Use lazy fetching `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`
- Use `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`

Some additional reading:

[A beginner’s guide to Hibernate Set and List behavior](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-favoring-sets-vs-bags/)

[Hibernate does not return distinct results for a query with outer join fetching enabled for a collection (even if I use the distinct keyword)?](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword)

Comment: Without hibernate, I can join more than two tables. Is it a limitation, that hibernate cannot join three tables? It works for me with `FetchType.LAZY` or with `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`, but that may be slower. It does not work using a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
@OneToMany
@LazyCollection(value=LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
private Collection<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
```